# Is the Svetavaraha Kalpa and the Padma Kalpa the same?

Tags: bhagavata-purana, time, varaha, prabhupada, kalpa

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu_units_of_time), the previous kalpa was known as the Padma kalpa:

> Currently, 50 years of Brahma have elapsed. **The last Kalpa at the end of 50th year is called Padma Kalpa**. We are currently in the first 'day' of the 51st year.[26] This Brahma's day, Kalpa, is named as Shveta-Varaha Kalpa.

However, A.C. Bhaktivedanta Swami Prabhupada in his commentary of the Srimad Bhagavatam 2.10.47 states:

> The present duration of a kalpa of Brahmā is called the Varāha-kalpa or Śvetavarāha-kalpa because the incarnation of the Lord as Varāha took place during the creation of Brahmā, who was born on the lotus coming out of the abdomen of Viṣṇu. **Therefore this Varāha-kalpa is also called Pādma-kalpa**, and this is testified by ācāryas like Jīva Gosvāmī as well as Viśvanātha Cakravartī Ṭhākura in pursuance of the first commentator, Svāmī Śrīdhara. So there is no contradiction between the Varāha and the Pādma-kalpa of Brahmā.

So then are the Padma Kalpa and the Svetavaraha Kalpa the same or different?

Comment: Both are not same. However, current Sveta Varaha Kalpa can otherwise be called as Brahma Kalpa or Padma Kalpa

Comment: Yeah I know. Prabhupada, Sridhara Swami and Jiva Goswami made mistakes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No the two are not the same and wikipedia is actually right on this point. According to [this excerpt from the Vishnu Purana](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp037.htm) they are certainly different:

> When the-three worlds are but one mighty ocean, Brahmá, who is one with Náráyańa, satiate with the demolition of the universe, sleeps upon his serpent-bed--contemplated, the lotus born, by the ascetic inhabitants of the Janaloka--for a night of equal duration with his day; at the close of which he creates anew. Of such days and nights is a year of Brahmá composed; and a hundred such years constitute his whole life. **One Parárddha, or half his existence, has expired, terminating with the Mahá Kalpa called Pádma. The Kalpa termed Váráha is the first of the second period of Brahmá's existence.**

Answer (score 2):

The above answer is partially correct because Sveta Varaha kalpa can also be called Padma kalpa. A kalpa is called Padma when there is a manifestation of the universe from lotus. Sri Viswanath Chakarvarti Thakur writes on SB 3.11.37

> "This  verse   describes   the first   day in  the fifty-first year    of  Brahma, in  the second
>   half    of  his life.       The Padma-kalpa (the    previous    day)    is  described   in  verses  such
>   as  padmam  kalpam  atho    srnu    (SB 2.10.47)    and the verses  after   udaplutam
>   visvam  idam    (SB 3.8.10),    with    a   description of  a   lotus   in  one ocean   of  water.
>       The appearance  of  one Brahma  with    no  one else    present is  described   in  vilokya
>   tatranyad   apasyamanah (SB 2.9.7)  Thus,   Brahma  did not see Sanaka  and the
>   others  who live    for the whole   of  Brahma’s    life.
>
> Because    of  these   verses, some    have    another explanation for the Padma-kalpa.
>
> They   say that    Mahaloka,   Janaloka,   Tapoloka    and Satyloka,   which   remain
>   without being   destroyed   until   the end of  the second  half    of  his life,   become
>   covered with    water   at  the end of  the first   half    of  Brahma’s    life    (thus   no  planets or
>   the great   sages   are not visible to  Brahma  on  the first   day of  his fifty-first year).
>   Those   who live    till    the end of  Brahma’s    life    on  those   planets enter   into    Narayana
>   along   with    Brahma  during  the night   at  the end of  the first   half    of  Brahma’s    life.
>   They    say that    the first   day in  the second  half    of  Brahma’s    life    (when   he  appears
>   on  a   lotus   and sees    no  planets and no  sages)  is  called  Sveta-varaha    or  Padma-
>   kalpa.  As  well,   in  the next    chapter it  will    be  explained   that    Sanaka, Marici  and
>   others  appeared    from    Brahma. This    is  similar to  the Brahma-kalpa.   That    day
>   cannot  be  called  Brahma-kalpa    since   it  comes   after   this    description of  the
>   Padma-kalpa.
>
> In verse   36  of  this    chapter,    describing  Padma-kalpa,    the word    ante    can mean    “at the end of  the first   day.”       Thus    the second  day after
>   Brahma’s    birth   could   be  called  the Padma-kalpa.        Ayam    tu  in  this
>   verse   then    means   that    the Padma-kalpa is  also    a   name    for the Varaha-
>   kalpa,  the first   day in  the second  half    of  Brahma’s    life.   It  is  called
>   Varaha-kalpa    because Varaha  avatara appeared    during  that    kalpa.  The
>   word    api after   dvitiyasya  indicates   that    even    the first   kalpa   of
>   Brahma’s    life    is  called  the Padma-kalpa.    This    is  the explanation of
>   some    persons.
>   "

In summary, this kalpa can also be called Padma because Sri Brahma recreated the planetary systems from the lotus in this kalpa.

Answer (score 2):

According to Padma Purana too, Padma Kalpa and Varaha Kalpa both are not same.

[Padma Purana, Srishti Khanda, Chapter 3 - Kinds of creation:](https://archive.org/details/padma_purana_part1_english/page/n43)

> At the end of the night which is of the same measure (as the day)he
>   again brings about the creation. Such is the year of Brahma and
>   likewise are his hundred years. Long is the life-span of that great
>   one, viz. one hundred years. **Only one Parardha (half of the span)
>   has rolled by, O sinless one. At the end of it there was the great
>   Kalpa known as Padma.** Of the second Parardha, O king, this present
>   Kalpa (called) Varaha is conceived to be the first one.

Currently we are living in the second Parardha, first Kalpa of the second Parardha is called Varaha and the last Kalpa of first Parardha was called Padma Kalpa. So both are different.