# Why does the Bhagavata Purana say the first Pararddha is already over when it is narrating the events of the Padma Kalpa?

Tags: bhagavata-purana, brahma, vishnu-purana, kalpa

***Note***: This is a follow-up of this [question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21211/is-the-svetavaraha-kalpa-and-the-padma-kalpa-the-same).

According to the Vishnu Purana, the Padma Kalpa terminates with the end of one Pararddha or the first half of Brahma's life and the commencement of Svetavaraha Kalpa signifies the beginning of second Pararddha:

> When the-three worlds are but one mighty ocean, Brahma, who is one with Narayana, satiate with the demolition of the universe, sleeps upon his serpent-bed--contemplated, the lotus born, by the ascetic inhabitants of the Janaloka--for a night of equal duration with his day; at the close of which he creates anew. Of such days and nights is a year of Brahma composed; and a hundred such years constitute his whole life. **One Parárddha, or half his existence, has expired, terminating with the Mahá Kalpa called Pádma. The Kalpa termed Váráha is the first of the second period of Brahmá's existence.** (**Vishnu Purana, Canto I, Chapter III**)

Now, the Srimad Bhagavatam states that it describes the events of the Padma Kalpa:

> O King, I shall in due course explain the measurements of time in its gross and subtle features with the specific symptoms of each, **but for the present let me explain unto you the Padma-kalpa**. (**Srimad Bhagavatam Canto II, Chapter X**)

However, in the Srimad Bhagavatam, it also states that the first Pararddha or the first half of Brahma's life is over:

> The one hundred years of Brahmā’s life are divided into two parts, the first half and the second half. **The first half of the duration of Brahmā’s life is already over, and the second half is now current.** (**Srimad Bhagavatam, Canto III, Chapter XI**)

So isn't the Srimad Bhagavatam contradicting the Vishnu Purana? How do we reconcile these verses?

Comment: if brahma only one? is He not born many many times?

Comment: Yes, of course, he's born many times. @Partha

Comment: How is this a contradiction? Narrating things that happened earlier should be the expected narration and even if was a future time, it would be explained by prophecy.

Answer (score 2):

The contradiction can be resolved when we understand that another name for Varaha kalpa is Padma Kalpa. A kalpa is called Padma when there is a manifestation of the universe from lotus. Apparently, there was a complete recreation of the universe at the beginning of this kalpa. Sri Viswanath Chakarvarti Thakur gives the explanation in his commentary on SB 3.11.37

> "This  verse   describes   the first   day in  the fifty-first year    of  Brahma, in  the second
>   half    of  his life.       The Padma-kalpa (the    previous    day)    is  described   in  verses  such
>   as  padmam  kalpam  atho    srnu    (SB 2.10.47)    and the verses  after   udaplutam
>   visvam  idam    (SB 3.8.10),    with    a   description of  a   lotus   in  one ocean   of  water.
>       The appearance  of  one Brahma  with    no  one else    present is  described   in  vilokya
>   tatranyad   apasyamanah (SB 2.9.7)  Thus,   Brahma  did not see Sanaka  and the
>   others  who live    for the whole   of  Brahma’s    life.
>
> Because    of  these   verses, some    have    another explanation for the Padma-kalpa.
>
> They   say that    Mahaloka,   Janaloka,   Tapoloka    and Satyloka,   which   remain
>   without being   destroyed   until   the end of  the second  half    of  his life,   become
>   covered with    water   at  the end of  the first   half    of  Brahma’s    life    (thus   no  planets or
>   the great   sages   are not visible to  Brahma  on  the first   day of  his fifty-first year).
>   Those   who live    till    the end of  Brahma’s    life    on  those   planets enter   into    Narayana
>   along   with    Brahma  during  the night   at  the end of  the first   half    of  Brahma’s    life.
>   They    say that    the first   day in  the second  half    of  Brahma’s    life    (when   he  appears
>   on  a   lotus   and sees    no  planets and no  sages)  is  called  Sveta-varaha    or  Padma-
>   kalpa.  As  well,   in  the next    chapter it  will    be  explained   that    Sanaka, Marici  and
>   others  appeared    from    Brahma. This    is  similar to  the Brahma-kalpa.   That    day
>   cannot  be  called  Brahma-kalpa    since   it  comes   after   this    description of  the
>   Padma-kalpa.
>
> In verse   36  of  this    chapter,    describing  Padma-kalpa,    the word    ante    can mean    “at the end of  the first   day.”       Thus    the second  day after
>   Brahma’s    birth   could   be  called  the Padma-kalpa.        Ayam    tu  in  this
>   verse   then    means   that    the Padma-kalpa is  also    a   name    for the Varaha-
>   kalpa,  the first   day in  the second  half    of  Brahma’s    life.   It  is  called
>   Varaha-kalpa    because Varaha  avatara appeared    during  that    kalpa.  The
>   word    api after   dvitiyasya  indicates   that    even    the first   kalpa   of
>   Brahma’s    life    is  called  the Padma-kalpa.    This    is  the explanation of
>   some    persons.
>   "

In summary, this kalpa can also be called Padma because Sri Brahma recreated the planetary systems from the lotus in this kalpa. 
Thus, Vishnu Purana and Bhagavata Purana are in agreement with each other.