# Any one answer this question

Tags: rama, mahabharata, kalpa, ramayana, daksha

Can any one answer this question?

[Reconciling the Kalpa Bheda between Devi Sati and Devi Parvati taking basis from the Puranas, including Srimad Bhagavata Purana](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/40436/28986)

Comment: You could have requested the answer in the comment section? Is it ok to post it as a seperate post @Mods Clarify?

Comment: @Shashaank Please raise a flag. Moderators will not be notified using "@Mods"

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because This question is asking for someone to answer another question with no new inputs or helpful suggestions.